# applyBlurWithRadius working on iPhone 6, not 6+ (UIImage+ImageEffects)

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, ios8

I'm using Apple's [`UIImage+ImageEffects`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/UIImage+BlurredFrame/0.0.3/Categories/UIImage+ImageEffects.html) category from WWDC (2013?)

This method works just fine on iPhone 6, but creates a really strange unblurred, oversaturated image on iPhone 6 Plus:

```
[self applyBlurWithRadius:60 tintColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.3] saturationDeltaFactor:2.4 maskImage:nil];
```

iPhone 6 (proper):

[image]

iPhone 6 Plus (weird):

[image]

Any idea what's going on?

**Update:** I've determined through trial and error that setting the blurRadius to anything less than or equal to 50 shows up OK, so it's related to the radius. I'd still like to know what exactly is causing it to goof on the larger screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this question is old and the OP has since moved on, but I would like to explain why it's different on each phone... for future generations.

The iPhone6 and the iPhone6+ have different screen resolutions. Mainly, the iPhone6 is has a scale of 2.0, while the iPhone6+ has a scale of 3.0.

***Why does this matter?***

In the source code for `applyBlurWithRadius` in the source file `UIImage+ImageEffects.m`, you will find these lines:

```
CGFloat inputRadius = blurRadius * [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
uint32_t radius = floor(inputRadius * 3. * sqrt(2 * M_PI) / 4 + 0.5);
if (radius % 2 != 1) {
    radius += 1; // force radius to be odd so that the three box-blur methodology works.
}
```

You can see that the `inputRadius` will be different based on what the scale of the screen is. So, on the iPhone6, this value will be `60*2` (end result for `radius` will be: 227), and on the iPhone6+ the value will be `60*3` (end result for `radius` will be 339). This will obviously produce the different results since they are different values.

As for why the color difference? I am pretty sure the `radius` shouldn't exceed 255 otherwise undefined results may occur (probably integer overflow, causing color components to wrap back to zero). Since the iPhone6+'s screen scale value pushes it above this value, you see weird results, but not on the iPhone6 since it's below that threshold.

You should be able to see the same weirdness happen on an iPhone6 by using the value of 90 for the `blurRadius` parameter.

*Side note*: You shouldn't need values above 30 for parameter `blurRadius` anyway -- the results won't be much different beyond that point.

Hope this helps you.